# Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a ActionController::Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch at /classifications
Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a ActionController::Parameters. -- {"1"=>"pumpkin text"}
```

In my classification model, I have the following serialization which corresponds with a mysql column named default_fields of type text:

```
serialize :default_fields, Array
```

In my view the name attribute looks like so:

```
<input id="classification_default_fields_n" name="classification[default_fields][1]" type="checkbox" value="pumpkin text">
```

And I could have multiple fields like this:

```
<input id="classification_default_fields_n" name="classification[default_fields][2]" type="checkbox" value="cucumber text">
<input id="classification_default_fields_n" name="classification[default_fields][3]" type="checkbox" value="orange text">
```

As you can see, I am expecting an array of strings in the variable default_fields. However, it is not trying these fields as an array. It is treating them as a hash of key/value pairs.

How can I address this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I get it now. If you want to send an array, then the brackets must be empty like so:

```
classification[default_fields][]"
```

If you want to send a hash, then the square bracket must contain a value that represents the key and the value is represented by the input data:

```
classification[default_fields][1]
```

Now if you want to send a collection (hash) of hashes, then the value in the brackets indicates the key of one of the hash elements:

```
classification[default_fields[1][key1]]
classification[default_fields[2][key2]]
```

Also add the correct serialization for what you want:

```
  serialize :default_fields, Hash
  # or
  serialize :default_fields, Array
```